# Выбор главного Activity через пользовательские настройки

Tags: java, android, activity

**Необходимо**:

1. При первом запуске приложения на устройстве выводить `Activity` с возможностью выбора страны (не локализация - разница в контенте).
2. При выборе сохраняются настройки, и при последующих запусках будет запускать выбранное `Activity` по стране.
3. Возможность менять в настройках выводимое `Activity`.

**Это вообще возможно?**

Нужно что бы пользователь сам выбирал себе одно из 2-3 `Activity`, которые отличаются только контентом.

Comment: Насколько и чем различется контент, что для него нужно создавать собственную активити?

Comment: я что то вообще не могу понять SharedPreferences. прочитал туториал но вообще не могу составить в голове картину как это подогнать.... кто может помочь с кодом, и объяснить?!

Answer (score 7):

1. всегда запускаете `activity main`  (к примеру)
2. `activity main` проверяет настройки, если страна не выбрана создает `intent` и переходит в `activityChooseCountry`
3. если страна выбрана, не выводя `view` перенаправляет (через intent) в нужную `activity`

получается, `activity main` служит как маршрутизатор. Перенаправляя в нужные `activity`

Comment: а есть рабочий пример у Вас? я новичок)

Comment: покажите свой код, который переходит по активити, потом разбиремся

Comment: воспользуюсь вашей подсказкой, постараюсь написать что то и потом покажу (завтра), спасибо =)

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, Вам стоит посмотреть в сторону SharedPreferences при инициализации приложения для сохранения настроек используйте этот механизм сохранения данных в файл. При повторном входе нужно проверять этот файл и запускать приложение согласно сохраненных в файле данных

Comment: в `ActivityMain` нужно и использовать `SharedPreferences`, по другому как можно проверить задан ли страна?

Comment: Чтобы при повторном запуске приложения использовался его сохраненный выбор пользователя, для этого идеален (Общие настройки SharedPreferences), разработанный специально для этих целей Приложение автоматически создаёт файл в своей папке и хранит простые данные в виде «ключ — значение». Весь процесс создания, открытия, чтения файла оптимизирован очень простой и избавляет от головной боли. Можно конечно хранить и в БД или специальных онлайн сервисах, но самый удобный и несложный способ, приемлимый в данной задаче - создание файла настроек при помощи класса SharedPreferences

Comment: вы правы. Но если хорошенко прочитаете вопрос и ответ, Вам будет понятно, что так и так человек использует `SharedPreferences` и он просит алгоритм дальше, после `SharedPreferences`. Без `SharedPreferences` мой ответ тоже не будет работать, так что автор вопроса это уже знает.

Comment: да согласен, не хватило внимательности. Да, нужны подробности. И тут действительно можно не плодить активити, а использовать фрагменты, как справедливо указал antop95

Comment: Ребята всем спасибо за ответы. Буду разбираться)

Answer (score 0):

Для таких случаев лучше всего использовать фрагменты:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Ребята всем спасибо за ответы. Буду разбираться)